# Замена файла index.html в зависимости от ширины экрана пользователя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему данный код работает только для файла `index-2.html`, а когда ширина меньше 767 пикселей то `index-3.html` не отображается?

```
doc_w = $(document).width();
if (doc_w < 1580 && doc_w >= 768) {
  window.location="index-2.html"; 
} else if(doc_w < 767 && doc_w >= 480) {
  window.location="index-3.html"; 
}
```

Comment: Почитайте справку: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Bharata Ваш вариант работает только с консолью, проблема в том что при проверке на разрешение от 768 до 480 второй иф не срабатывает

Comment: это неправда! Вы видимо просто не заметили: я написал где ваша ошибка: замените у себя `< 767` на `< 768` и всё будет работать у вас.

Comment: @Bharata Ответ по прежнему не помог но галочку поставил

Comment: А что не получается? Вы заменили `< 767` на `< 768`?

Comment: Я уже сам увидел [что у вас не получается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839544/Не-срабатывает-оператор-if-на-разрешении-768-и-ниже-jquery), но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас небольшая ошибка - надо писать:

`else if(doc_w < 768 && doc_w >= 480)`

```js
function check(doc_w)
{
 if(doc_w < 1580 && doc_w >= 768)
 {
  console.log("index-2.html"); 
 }
 else if(doc_w < 768 && doc_w >= 480)
 {
  console.log("index-3.html"); 
 }
}
check(766);
check(767);
check(768);
```