# Не срабатывает оператор if на разрешении 768 и ниже . Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var win_w = $('body').width();
  if (win_w < 768) {
    console.log('if on');
  }
  console.log('if off'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Почему данный кусок кода работает только когда вместо 768 поставить 1024 и выше -____- При изменении ширины окна через devise toolbar google chrome
Код находится перед закрывающимся body, jquery выше подключен..хэлп

Comment: @Igor Работает вплоть до разрешения 964 пикселя в ширину

Comment: у вас случайно не установлен тег meta viewport , возможно в теге meta viewport указана ширина 1024 или 964?

Comment: @Igor спасибо! Реально совсем про viewport забыл, и сидел тупил..Спасибо)

Comment: @SelinCorvin это был комментарий md5hash

Comment: @Igor вот до сих пор еще туплю, и вам спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте событие `resize`:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var win_w = $('body').width();
  if (win_w < 768) {
    console.log(win_w, 'if on');
  } else {
    console.log(win_w, 'if off'); 
  }
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Работает вплоть до разрешения 964 пикселя в ширину

Comment: @SelinCorvin не понял комментарий

Comment: я меняю разрешение окна, в консоль выводится это разрешение + надпись if on / if off (как в Вашем примере). Но когда доходит до 964 пикселей то этот код не работает

Comment: Суть вообще в том чтобы на 3-х разрешениях загружать разные версии сайта, 480, 768. 1600, но после 964 не пашет

Comment: @SelinCorvin пожалуйста, не пишите "код не работает". Описывайте, что происходит/не происходит.

Comment: @SelinCorvin Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: @SelinCorvin У Вас лишняя пустая пара скобок `{}` после `else if (...)`.